# SQL: START WITH ____ IN Clause Performance

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a query that looks something like this:

```
START WITH Table1.value1 IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT value2 from Table2)
```

How can I change it to a join such that it looks something like this?

```
START WITH 
(SELECT DISTINCT value1 from Table1
INNER JOIN value2 from Table2
ON value1 = value2)
```

The above query by itself doesn't work, and I can't figure out how to make it work. Here's the error: 
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 10

Basically I'm trying to replace IN with a JOIN to improve performance, but I don't know how to do it if the IN is preceded by a START WITH.

Comment: What error are you getting back? It may be an aliasing issue if Table2 contains a column called value1

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with? I don't recognize that Start with clause. ps: saying it doesn't work won't help much. Write the error message, at least

Comment: Here's the error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 10

Comment: I have a CONNECT BY later

Comment: Why do you belive that the join will improve performance ? Is there an index on colum `value1` iin table1 ? Please generate EXPLAIN PAN for your query and append it to the question (as a text - not a bitmap, please!!!).

Comment: Show us your **complete** query

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` syntax is wrong, or at least the one on the query you posted.

Try to make the `JOIN` like this:

```
START WITH 
(SELECT DISTINCT value1 from Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON table1.value1 = table2.value2)
```